# "Not a valid month" on an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have an sql statement:

```
Insert into MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 (ID,MY_DATE) values (167600,to_timestamp('15-APR-14 01.36.58.803000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'));
```

As I read this format is correct (as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)) but oracle returns an error `SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month`. Any idea how to solve this problem? I use Oracle Database 11b Express Edition.

Comment: Is `my_date` a date or timestamp field? If it's a date, what are your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` set to? Sounds like an implicit conversion problem. Or maybe less likely an `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` problem.

Comment: NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE being set to a language where the abbreviation for April isn't APR sounds like a good bet.

Comment: MikeW, As I read on oracle site, MON is a valid month format.
@AlexPoole , This is a timestamp format. NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=RR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SSXFF

Comment: MY_DATE is a TIMESTAMP(3) and NLS_DATE_FORMAT=RR/MM/DD. BTW, does it matter? I thought that the second parameter for `to_timestamp` function is a timestamp format.

Comment: It only matters if there is implicit conversion going on; if `my_date` is a timestamp (despite the confusing name) then there isn't, and if there was the NLS formats match anyway. So that leaves `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` being wrong; or is there a trigger on the table setting a date/timestamp field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a trigger on the table that is setting a date or timestamp column, which would give some indication in the full error stack, it sounds like your `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not expecting an English-language month abbreviation.

What you have is valid in English:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'RR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SSXFF';
alter session set nls_date_language ='ENGLISH';

select to_timestamp('15-APR-14 01.36.58.803000000 PM',
  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') as my_date
from dual;

MY_DATE                   
---------------------------
14/04/15 13:36:58.803000000
```

But if your session's default date language is Polish (guessing from your profile) it will give this error - with the error message still in English:

```
alter session set nls_date_language ='POLISH';

select to_timestamp('15-APR-14 01.36.58.803000000 PM',
  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') as my_date
from dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

If you don't want to set your session to English you can override that for a specific statement by giving the [optional third parameter to `to_timestamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions213.htm):

```
alter session set nls_date_language ='POLISH';

select to_timestamp('15-APR-14 01.36.58.803000000 PM',
  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as my_date
from dual;

MY_DATE                   
---------------------------
14/04/15 13:36:58.803000000
```

You can also avoid the issue entirely by using month numbers instead of month names, or using the ANSI [timestamp literal syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17118/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

```
select timestamp '2014-04-15 13:36:58.803' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2014-04-1513:36:58.803'
---------------------------------
14/04/15 13:36:58.803000000
```

These methods also all work for date columns; [the `to_date()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm) is affected by NLS settings in the same way and has the same optional date language parameter.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. The problem is that I'm using sqldeveloper and it stores information about NLS table. I didn't know that local app can store those kind of information.