# not a valid month in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

what is wrong with this query

```
INSERT INTO course VALUES (10,'Technology Concepts',1195,NULL,'DSCHERER',TO_DATE('29-MAR-2007 20:14:33','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'ARISCHER',TO_DATE('05-APR-2007 20:14:33','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` for `courses`

Comment: [Possibly a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24990294/266304); NLS settings would be helpful, particularly `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, but also do you have a trigger on the table? And for fixed dates you could also use the ANSI literal `TIMESTAMP '2007-03-29 20:14:33'` syntax, even inserting into a date column.

Comment: I think there is a conflict because I am running oracle in Win7 french language, how can i fix that, how i make oracle use english months instead of french ?

Comment: @SerenityTn - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24990663/266304) applies for `to_date()` as well as `to_timestamp()`. If that answers your question we can close this as a duplicate? Mat's advice still applies though as an alternative.

Comment: thank you guys i executed the following instruction and it works now
alter session set nls_date_language ='ENGLISH';

Comment: yes it's duplicate sorry for that, i've been searching for solution but didn't thought that language cause problem

Comment: If you CAN, try to avoid month names (JAN, FEB, ...), and use month numbering (1, 2, 3, ...). Certainly if you are in a multi-language environment. You should also enter the format anyway, so what is forcing you to use month names ? The internal date storage doesn't know month names, it has to convert everytime (date is a decimal number). Don't bother with names.

Comment: Always add the column names in an Insert statement (before the VALUES keyword). Always. There's lots of reason to do that, and there's very few to not do.

Comment: thank you a lot for your precious advice tvCa, I will surely avoid to use naming.

Comment: @SerenityTn: you should not *avoid* using names, you should **use** them, e.g. `insert into course (course_id, title, ...) values ...`